# Días Sábados y Domingos por Rango de fecha

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, funciones

Espero, esten bien.

Necesito saber cuantos sábados y domingos hay por rango de fecha.

Cómo podría hacer eso en php?

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida te recomiendo leer como preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que tu cuestión sea bien recibida por la comunidad; pues se espera el código  minimo que haz tratado y donde has tenido errores

Comment: del mismo modo mira como agregar un ejemplo mínimo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: $starDate = new DateTime('2018-06-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2018-06-30');
while( $starDate <= $endDate){
     if($starDate->format('l')== 'Saturday' || $starDate->format('l')== 'Sunday'){
                    echo $starDate->format('y-m-d (D)')."<br/>";
     }
     $starDate->modify("+1 days");
                
}

Answer (score 5):

ok ... ya resolvi el problema

```
$starDate = new DateTime('2018-06-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2018-06-30');
while( $starDate <= $endDate){
     if($starDate->format('l')== 'Saturday' || $starDate->format('l')== 'Sunday'){
                    echo $starDate->format('y-m-d (D)')."<br/>";
     }
     $starDate->modify("+1 days");

}
```

espero que también les sirva